# Merge 2 arrays into 1 array and filter this merged array,

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter, react-hooks

So I have 2 arrays of objects: planned, backlog.

```
    const planned = [
     {
      order_number: "1",
      part_name: "example",
      part_number: "1",
      process_id: 1
     },
     ....
    ];
    const backlog = [
     {
      order_number: "2",
      part_name: "example",
      part_number: "2",
      process_id: 2
     },
     ....
    ];
```

I am trying to filter both of them at the same time, each one individually that's not a problem.

So what I am actually doing is first adding key of planned to planned array and backlog to backlog array in order to know later from where the order originally came from.

```
var newPlanned = planned.map(function (el) {
  var o = Object.assign({}, el);
  o.planned = true;
  return o;
});

var newBacklog = backlog.map(function (el) {
  var o = Object.assign({}, el);
  o.backlog = true;
  return o;
});
```

Later I am merging the 2 arrays into 1 array, and filtering the merged array with one input onChange, but what I can't achieve is to render the "planned" and "backlog" arrays separately from the new merged array.

```
const newPlannedAndBacklog = [...newBacklog, ...newPlanned];
```

Link to codeSandBox:
[SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-grass-kb4sh?file=/src/App.js:0-2377)

Comment: Good, now it would help to see how you're trying to render the array and where it fails.

Answer (score 1):

I added a `type` instead of a boolean property for *several* types. This may be more scalable so you can add more types (refined, done, etc.), but let me know if you'd like the boolean property.

```
const combinedList = [
  ...planned.map((item) => ({ ...item, type: 'planned' })),
  ...backlog.map((item) => ({ ...item, type: 'backlog' })),
];

const getFilteredList = (type) => combinedList.filter((item) => item.type === type);
```

### UPDATE

I believe this is the behavior you want. Let me know if not and I'll update the answer.

```
// Combines all backlog and planned stories into one array
const newPlannedAndBacklog = [
  ...planned.map((item) => ({ ...item, type: 'planned' })),
  ...backlog.map((item) => ({ ...item, type: 'backlog' })),
];

// Filters property values based on input value
const getFilteredList = (filter) => newPlannedAndBacklog
  .filter(item => Object
    .values(item)
    .map(String)
    .some(v => v.includes(filter))
  );

export default function App() {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({});
  const [stories, setStories] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setForm({ [name]: value });
    setStories(getFilteredList(value));
  };

  // Separates the return of getfilteredList based on type
  const renderDiv = (type) => stories
    .filter((story) => story.type === type)
    .map((story) => {

      // Render each property individually:
      return Object.entries(story).map(([key, value]) => {
        const content = <>{key}: {value}</>;

        if (key === 'order_number') return <h3>{content}</h3>;
        return <p>{content}</p>;
      });
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>PlannedAndBacklog</h2>
      <p>Search for planned and backlog:</p>
      <input
        name='type'
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={form.type || ''}
      />
      <div>{renderDiv('backlog')}</div>
      <div>{renderDiv('planned')}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, how can I filter the combinedList with one input with onChange and show it in 2 speared divs?

Comment: Are you trying to search on all of the item properties? In other words, do you want to search for `example` and have all of the items still show up?